# Почему не работает min-width, width auto?

Tags: css, веб-программирование

Только что столкнулся с такой проблемой, создал элемент div с классом test и дал этому классу bg red и он занял всю ширину экрана, так же попробовал дать min-width 100px и тоже самое. Это че такое? Впервые такое вижу, стилей больше никаких нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тебе нужен max-width, ты немного не понял ...)))

Comment: Когда ты будешь сужать браузер то твой див не уменьшиться меньше 100px, вот что такое min-width

Comment: Ну, а что касается того, что занимает всю ширину экрана, так это в первом же уроке по верстке рассказывают, что блочный элемент занимает всю свободную ширину родителя а строчный растягивается  на сколько это растянет его контент

Answer (score 0):

`div` по умолчанию - блочный элемент, минимальная ширина ему на данный момент безразлична, дайте ему `inline-block`, чтобы он схлопнулся от отсутствия контента и тогда минимальная ширина сработает:

```css
.test {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: товарищи минусаторы, объясняйте причину!

Comment: @PeterKolosov видимо им мой русский режет слух до ваших правок) я ее принял, чтобы не обижать здешних неженок)

Comment: Минус мой, так как  считаю, что не отвечает на вопрос... Перечитайте вопрос и ответ... Может поймете в чем суть вопроса